# keras - no module named tensorflow

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to use Keras with tensorflow-gpu using docker image https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker But keras is using cpu version of tensorflow. I have cpu and gpu version of tensorflow

cpu

```
root@08b5fff06800:~# pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: tensorflow-tensorboard, six, protobuf, mock, numpy, backports.weakref, wheel
```

gpu

```
root@08b5fff06800:~# pip show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 0.12.1
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: mock, numpy, protobuf, wheel, six
```

so i read in this thread it tell me to uninstall tensorflow so it will use tensorflow-gpu. but after i uninstall tensorflow and i run a code it tells me
no module named tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem installing it too. What I did was I uninstalled Tensorflow GPU. Then you can try to reinstall it. Make sure you are also using CUDNN and Cuda 9.0 for your graphics drivers.